# Stretchable vertical skip with mdframed

Tags: vertical-alignment, mdframed

I created an mdframed-based theorem environment as follows:

```
\newmdtheoremenv[outerlinewidth=0pt,
leftmargin=0pt,rightmargin=0pt,
innerleftmargin=4pt,outermargin=0pt,
innermargin=0pt,innerrightmargin=4pt,
innerbottommargin=2pt,innertopmargin=3pt,
skipbelow=1.5ex plus2pt minus2pt,
skipabove=1.5ex plus2pt minus2pt]{theoreme}[dummy]{Théorème}
```

with, I think, an elastic vertical stretch when needed before and after the frame. What's strange is that the `\flushbottom` option is ignored when the frame is split across pages, as illustrated below:

[image]

Is there an mdframed option that handles this issue?

A MWE is suggested below:

```
\documentclass[11pt,fleqn]{book}
\usepackage{lipsum}
\usepackage{amsmath,amsthm}
\usepackage[framemethod=tikz]{mdframed}
\usepackage[showframe,top=3.2cm,bottom=3.2cm,left=3.25cm,right=3.25cm,headsep=12pt,a4paper]{geometry}
\theoremstyle{plain}
\newmdtheoremenv[backgroundcolor=red!10,%
innerbottommargin=2pt,innertopmargin=3pt,%
skipbelow=1.5ex plus2pt minus2pt,%
skipabove=1.5ex plus2pt minus2pt,linecolor=red!50]{theorem}{Theorem}
\begin{document}
\chapter{Title}
\lipsum[1-3]
\begin{theorem}\lipsum[1-2]
\end{theorem}
\end{document}
```

Comment: Can you provide a [minimal working example (MWE)](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/228).  The picture you provide needs mode than your code snippet to create it.  Also do you mean "`flushbottom` option", if so to what, or "`\flushbottom` command"?

Comment: @AndrewSwann I just edited my message. This should show the problem. Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Adding a stretchable space before the break seems to do the trick.  This is done via the option:

```
 beforebreak={\vspace{0pt plus 1filll}}
```

Less stretchable fills get swallowed.  The example below gives

[image: Bottom of page 1]

at the bottom of page 1, and

[image: Bottom of page 2]

at the bottom of page 2.

```
\documentclass[11pt,fleqn]{book}

\usepackage{lipsum}

\usepackage{amsmath,amsthm}

\usepackage[framemethod=tikz]{mdframed}

\usepackage[showframe,top=3.2cm,bottom=3.2cm,left=3.25cm,right=3.25cm,headsep=12pt,a4paper]{geometry}

\theoremstyle{plain}
\newmdtheoremenv[backgroundcolor=red!10,%
innerbottommargin=2pt,innertopmargin=3pt,%
skipbelow=1.5ex plus2pt minus2pt,%
skipabove=1.5ex plus 2pt minus2pt,
beforebreak={\vspace{0pt plus 1filll}},
linecolor=red!50]{theorem}{Theorem}

\begin{document}

\chapter{Title}

\lipsum[1-3]

\begin{theorem}
  \lipsum[1-2]
\end{theorem}

\lipsum[4-6]

\begin{theorem}
  \lipsum[7-8]
\end{theorem}

\end{document}
```

Comment: It is interesting but in a sense not entirely satisfactory since the stretch only affects the box, and is not evenly distributed over the page. It would be nice to have all the stretches of the current page combined to this one.

Comment: A nice compromise would be a mix of `\pagebreak` and `mdframed box breaks`.